# zuul API Gateway Filter

Tags: spring, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am facing problem when i trying to access another REST API(registered in ZUUL route) from zuul pre-filter, the call is becoming recursive i.e its running my pre-filter code again and again. My Usecase is as follows-

1. In Zuul `PreFilter` `run()` method, I am validating the token passed in the header.
2. After validating the token, I am calling one rest service(User Location Service) to fetch the user details. My User Location Service is itself registered in ZUUL as below:

   ```
   user-location-service:
     path: /userLocationService/**
     url: http://localhost:9002
   ```

The problem is that the JWT token validation code is running again and again, Can you please suggest some solution where I can apply the call Userlocation service so that the `PreFilter` code would not run again and again?

Comment: can you tell me why you use pre filter for validation. Are you use OAuth 2.0 ?

Comment: No Thamira...We are validating only JWT Token in pre-filter.

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth-jwt

Answer (score 2):

Your User Location Service is registred in Zuul. So, all the times your filter is going to be executed when you got caugth in an infinite loop.

There are two approaches here:

- Do not pass again to the gateway and call direct User Location Service
- OR, Create a filter rule in your ZUll Authentication Filter to not consider the User Location Service. You can use the URL Path Context to exclude this route to be executed

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rafael. Yes you are right, we have chosen the first option as our solution.

Comment: when we are using 1st, we are not use dynamic hosting.

Answer (score 1):

you need to allow sensitiveHeaders.

```
     zuul:
        routes:
            resource:
                path: /resource/**
                url: http://localhost:8002/
                sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```

Comment: the problem in here is zuul not give permission to send authorize header. sensitiveHeaders gives that permission.